# Switching back-n-forth between virtual console(tty) while running Qt/Embedded

Tags: c++, c, qt, linux-kernel, tty

Using Qt/Embedded as the programming language for developing GUI, finds it impossible to switch to another virtual console (TTY) , while QWS server is running on the current terminal. This causes a lot inconvenience e.g. people redirects the outputs/log messages of the program to some other terminal & they very often see those log, while executing the software. It is particularly useful for debugging large projects.

I wonder, whether there is any way to make switching between virtual consoles work.

Re: I was just going through the source code of Qt/Embedded. I found this portion

```
    QWSKeyboardHandler::KeycodeAction ka;
    ka = m_handler->processKeycode(code, value != 0, value == 2);

    switch (ka) {
    case QWSKeyboardHandler::CapsLockOn:
    case QWSKeyboardHandler::CapsLockOff:
        switchLed(LED_CAPSL, ka == QWSKeyboardHandler::CapsLockOn);
        break;

    case QWSKeyboardHandler::NumLockOn:
    case QWSKeyboardHandler::NumLockOff:
        switchLed(LED_NUML, ka == QWSKeyboardHandler::NumLockOn);
        break;

    case QWSKeyboardHandler::ScrollLockOn:
    case QWSKeyboardHandler::ScrollLockOff:
        switchLed(LED_SCROLLL, ka == QWSKeyboardHandler::ScrollLockOn);
        break;

    default:
        // ignore console switching and reboot
        break;
    }
```

thought there will be a scope of modification to get desired behavior.

[Here is the whole source](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/source/b510e64cc5405c0664200bf471b5ccbbe3b4d081%3asrc/gui/embedded/qkbdlinuxinput_qws.cpp)